# How to prevent "algorithm did not converge" errors in neuralnet / Caret / R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, r-caret

I am trying to train a neural network using `train` function and `neuralnet` as my `method` paramater to predict times table.

I am scaling my training data set as well.

Even though I've tried different `learningrate`s, `stepmax`es, and `threshold`s for my `neuralnet`, each time I tried to train the network using `train` function one of the k-folds happened to fail every time saying

> 1: Algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax. 
>   2: predictions failed for Fold05.Rep1: layer1=8, layer2=0, layer3=0 Error in cbind(1, pred) %*% weights[[num_hidden_layers + 1]] : 
>     requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

I am guessing that this is because of weights being random so somehow each time I happen to get some weights that are not going to converge.

Is there anyway of preventing this? Maybe trying to re-train the particular fold which has failed using different weights?

Here is my code:

```r
library(caret)
library(neuralnet)

# Create the dataset
tt = data.frame(multiplier = rep(1:10, times = 10), multiplicand = rep(1:10, each = 10))
tt = cbind(tt, data.frame(product = tt$multiplier * tt$multiplicand))

# Splitting 
indexes = createDataPartition(tt$product,
                              times = 1,
                              p = 0.7,
                              list = FALSE)
tt.train = tt[indexes,]
tt.test = tt[-indexes,]

# Pre-process

preProc <- preProcess(tt, method = c('center', 'scale'))
tt.preProcessed <- predict(preProc, tt)
tt.preProcessed.train <- tt.preProcessed[indexes,]
tt.preProcessed.test <- tt.preProcessed[-indexes,]

# Train

train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                              number = 10,
                              repeats = 3)

tune.grid <- expand.grid(layer1 = 8,
                         layer2 = 0,
                         layer3 = 0)

tt.cv <- train(product ~ .,
               data = tt.preProcessed.train,
               method = 'neuralnet',
               tuneGrid = tune.grid,
               trControl = train.control,
               linear.output = TRUE,
               algorithm = 'backprop',
               learningrate = 0.01,
               stepmax = 500000,
               lifesign = 'minimal',
               threshold = 0.01)
```

Comment: did you normalize your train and test/validation data? (normalize columnwise - so that max val is 1 - the values in a column should be between 0 and 1).

Comment: Yes, I did using `preProcess()`. I've tried both normalizing and standardizing.